# How do I implement backup and restore using serialisation with multiple classes?

Tags: java, swing, object, serialization, arraylist

Im trying to serialise objects(Names and notes) which I store in my JTable. I want to be able to save this information to a file and when I load the program, the information should  load into the JTable. When I click the backup button a file is being created, but there is no data being stored. Could someone please guide me in the right direction and inform me what im doing wrong? My code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class tableTest {

private JFrame frame;
private JTable table;
private JTextField notesTextField;
private JTextField nameTextField;
private List l;

public tableTest() {
    new Serial().serialize(l);
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 900);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane1.setBackground(new Color(189, 183, 107));
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane1.addTab("Table", null, Panel, null);
    Panel.setLayout(null);

    final JPanel Add = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane1.addTab("Add to table", null, Add, null);
    Add.setLayout(null);

    nameTextField = new JTextField();
    nameTextField.setBounds(428, 211, 308, 34);
    Add.add(nameTextField);
    nameTextField.setColumns(10);

    notesTextField = new JTextField();
    notesTextField.setColumns(10);
    notesTextField.setBounds(428, 270, 308, 34);
    Add.add(notesTextField);

    JButton btnAddToTable = new JButton("Add to table");
    btnAddToTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            DefaultTableModel dtm =(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            dtm.addRow(new Object[] { nameTextField.getText(),
                    notesTextField.getText() });

        }
    });
    btnAddToTable.setBounds(472, 375, 103, 23);
    Add.add(btnAddToTable);

    JButton btnBackup = new JButton("Backup");
    btnBackup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            new Serial().deSerialize();
        }
    });
    btnBackup.setBounds(613, 375, 103, 23);
    Add.add(btnBackup);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 1039, 733);
    Panel.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(

    new String[] { "Names", "Notes" }, 0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                tableTest window = new tableTest();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class List implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList<Person> pList;

public List(){

    pList = new ArrayList<Person>();
}

public void addPerson(Person p) {
    pList.add(p);

}

public ArrayList<Person> getpList() {
    return pList;
}

public void setpList(ArrayList<Person> pList) {
    this.pList = pList;
}

}



import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Serial {

private List l;

public void serialize(List l) {

    try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("address.ser")) {

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        os.writeObject(l);

        os.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public List deSerialize() {

    try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("address.ser")) {

        ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        List l;

        l = (List) os.readObject();

        os.close();



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return l;


}
}



import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String pName;

public Person(String pName){
    setpName(pName);
}

public String getpName() {
    return pName;
}

public void setpName(String pName) {
    this.pName = pName;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be doing things backwards. i.e.,

- You should *serialize* not *de-serialize* when you back up.
- You should do the opposite when you restore.
- And you appear to be doing this completely backwards by calling deserialize in your backup button's ActionListener and serialize in your class creation code.
- Edit: Also, you're serializing an object of custom type List but are never adding data from your table's model to List. So List will never hold relevant data, and so your serialization will be futile. Instead either serialize the DefaultTableModel, or transfer the model's data to the List object before serializing it.

Also, unrelated but I feel important advice:

- You should test complex new concepts in very simple program at first, one without a GUI, one without all this unrelated and unnecessary complexity. So get rid of your GUI and get your serialization and deserializaation working **first**, and only then incorporate it into your greater and more complex program with the GUI.
- You should not use a `null` layout and calling `setBounds(...)` on your components to place them with absolute positioning as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.
- You will want to rename your custom List class so that it's name doesn't conflict with the important `java.util.List` class.

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment:

> So once the data has been entered into the JTable, it should be transfered to the list object before serialization? How would I go about doing this?

What I would do would be to get rid of the List class entirely, I would pass the Table's model into my serialize method, I would call `getDataVector()` on my DefaultTableModel object to extract its nucleus, and I would serialize that.

When de-serializing, I'd do the opposite -- read in the Vector from the disk and create a new DefaultTableModel object from it, from a `Vector<String>` that holds the table's column headings. As for the code details, well that's for you to work out.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm sorry to tell you this, but it really **is** just you. Ask your kids and they'll confirm it.

Comment: So once the data has been entered into the JTable, it should be transfered to the list object before serialization? How would I go about doing this?